# Checar se 'Permitir locais fictícios' está habilitado

Tags: android

Tenho um aplicativo que necessita da opção "Permitir locais fictícios" do aplicativo padrão de Galeria habilitada para que funcione.
Como verificar se ela está habilitada?
Como enviar o usuário para este item de meu caso esteja desabilitado?
Essa opção fica no menu Programador, é um menu escondido... Como ativar esse menu e enviar a pessoa até la?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resolvi...

Para verificar se a opção está habilitada:

```
private boolean isMockSettingsON() {
        return !Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION).equals("0");
}
```

Para enviar o usuário até o menu de dev:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta, o objeto `Location` possui uma propriedade de informa se ela foi gerada por mock, [isFromMockProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#isFromMockProvider()).

Esta está disponível a partir da API 18.

Exemplo:

```
if(!location.isFromMockProvider()){
 // Esta localização não foi gerada por um simulador
}
```